# HOW to get location information by IP address in php

Tags: php, ip, ip-address

i want get **Country Code , State Code, city name,** by ip address

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party services like https://www.ip2location.com which will provide you all details you require. you have to call rest api of such services and that service will return data to you

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use this API to get information like country_code,country_name, region_code,region_name, city,zipcode,latitude, longitude,metro_code,areacode

$location = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
print_r($location);


  { "ip": "77.99.179.98",
  "country_code": "GB",
  "country_name": "United Kingdom",
  "region_code": "H9",
  "region_name": "London, City of",
  "city": "London",
  "zipcode": "",
  "latitude": 51.5142,
  "longitude": -0.0931,
  "metro_code": "",
  "areacode": "" }
```

Comment: This service is no longer in use